# Java Style Guide XSD - Does One Exist?

Tags: java, xsd

Has anyone found an XSD for google's java style guide? Or anybody's style guide, for that matter? I'm trying to figure out the possible values for a setting in the XML. As an example, what does "3" mean in the following setting?

```
<option name="WHILE_BRACE_FORCE" value="3" />
```

I'd like to find this answer for all of the possible options and their possible values.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a IDE specific style definition or a CheckStyle definition? If so, look at the documentation of that IDE or of CheckStyle.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @MarkRotteveel. I still haven't found what I need, but this points me in the right direction. Sorry for an invalid question.

Comment: You seem to be looking at the IntelliJ style definition for the Google Java style, see https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/intellij-java-google-style.xml